# Share Song or audio from iPhone Music library to WhatsApp Fails

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, whatsapp

I am sharing audio file after getting it from iPhone Music Library. After successfully getting path of audio, I implemented following lines of code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if ( [self isWhatsAppInstalled] )
                    {
                        _docControll            = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:songPath]];
                        _docControll.UTI        = @"net.whatsapp.audio";
                        _docControll.delegate   = self;

                        [_docControll presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:view animated: YES];

                    } else {
                        [self alertWhatsappNotInstalled];
                    }

                });
```

It opens dialogue in whatsapp to send audio, so I press to send and whatsapp shows progress that audio is sending, but meanwhile it fails.

Here is the path: "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9FE7FD43-6521-4E9E-A400-21C9FF03EE27/Documents/audio.waa"

I tried two formats of audio waa and mp3.

Audio successfully sent if it is being sent from Main Bundle.

Any Help will really be appretiated.

> Blockquote